# Display an image from Python data in Kivy

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

```
import numpy as np
z = np.arange(300).reshape(10,10,3)
```

The last dimension represents the rgb value for 10 by 10 matrix. How can i display my data in rgb format as an image?

What i know from kivy, one can use

```
kivy.image(source='filename.png')
```

Comment: See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27153327/display-a-numpy-array-in-kivy for a way to do it using the Texture class.

Comment: Is it allowed to use Scipy,PIL in Kivy. Can one build application in android using these libraries?

Comment: You can use any python library. Scipy won't work on android or ios though, if that's what you're trying.

Comment: I think i can use opencv and it is also possible to build apk file using opencv