# showing PIL ImageGrab as numpy Array in Kivy Window

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, kivy, python-imaging-library, screen-capture

I am trying to capture a part of my screen with `PIL.ImageGrab` and then converting it to an `numpy.array` as you can see below.

```
np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0, 0, 720, 480)))
```

What I can't figure out is, how to get this data into a `Kivy` window or a widget?

All my Widgets are in separate classes so I would like to have one `Screen` class with all the code necessary for this part of my `Window`.

I have already tried methods like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27153327/display-a-numpy-array-in-kivy), but I don't know how to implement it since `Kivy` confuses me a lot sometimes.

If my idea just isn't realizable, I guess you could save each captured frame as `.jpg` format and then load it into `Kivy`. But I imagine this is not the most efficient way.

Thanks a lot in advance! Dominik